# how are functions of the form $f(x)=ax^{-b}+c$ called?

Tags: terminology

What is the name for the class of functions of the form:

\begin{equation}
f(x)=ax^{-b}+c\;.
\end{equation}

With $c=0$ and $a$ satisfying some normalization property these functions are called power laws, because they describe a probabilistic law. Even with $c=0$ I don't know how these type of functions are called. It seems to me that 'hyperbolic' is not the right term here.

Comment: not sure what *power laws* have to do with *probabilistic laws*

Comment: I would call it a *shifted* power law, even though this is ambiguous because the shift could be on $x$ as well.

Comment: Mathematics is about analysis and reasoning, not about calling names, in my humble opinion. If people are fond of extensive classifications with three part names in Latin (and you need those long names, due to the sheer number of objects to be named), I can recommend other subjects, like entomology.

Comment: @ProfessorVector:  Don't you mean etymology?

Comment: thanks ProfessorVector for that enlightening lecture. 
@gt6989b: In probability theory the law of a random variable $X$ is the function: $a\mapsto \mathbb P(X\leq a)$ ... or maybe its derivative, I don't remember. If $X$ has a density $f(a):=\frac{\partial P(X\leq a)}{\partial a}=a^{-\beta}/N$, then this law is referred to as the \textit{power law}.

Comment: @YvesDaoust *Shifted power law* sounds most appropriate to me as well

Comment: @ProfessorVector: I can't agree with you. Without names, which are shorthands for lengthy definitions, any mathematical statement would be nightmarish. "The *positive* *number* which, when *multiplied* by itself, yields the value $2$ does not belong to the *set* of the *numbers* which are the result of the *division* of an *integer* *number* by another." And "There is only $1$ *element* in the set of *numbers* such that there are exactly $2$ *integers* that yield no *remainder* when *dividing* by them, which belongs to the *set* of *integers* that are the product of an *integer* and $2$."

Comment: @Yves Daoust I objected against replacing a clear, symbolic definition like  $\begin{equation}
f(x)=ax^{-b}+c
\end{equation}$ by some vague and ambiguous "shifted power law", and you are insinuating I object against using a symbol $1$ instead of a wordy definition?! You must be kidding.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: who said that the expression would be used without a definition ? Please don't be bad faith.